# Sqlite3 database disk image malformed after hard reboot when using Greenwithenvy, where is the db stored?

Tags: database, sqlite, python-3.7, ubuntu-20.04

**Hello fellow linux-users!**

After tweaking my gpu with GWE (greenwithenvy) the system frooze and I had to do a hard reset.

Now the GWE-app won'r run due to a malformed sqlite3 db.

**What I've tried:**

0. Total purge of sqlite3-, flatpak-, gwe-files.
1. Reinstalled sqlite3-paks, flatpak-, gwe-files

**My question is:**
Where is this db stored on the computer? I really don't know where to look!

**When I execute the command:**
*flatpak run com.leinardi.gwe -v*

**I get the following:**

```
CRITICAL: Uncaught exception
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/app/lib/python3.7/site-packages/peewee.py", line 3099, in execute_sql
    cursor.execute(sql, params or ())
sqlite3.DatabaseError: database disk image is malformed

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/app/bin/gwe", line 54, in <module>
    __main__.main()

  File "/app/lib/python3.7/site-packages/gwe/__main__.py", line 100, in main
    _init_database()

  File "/app/lib/python3.7/site-packages/gwe/__main__.py", line 94, in _init_database
    Setting

  File "/app/lib/python3.7/site-packages/peewee.py", line 3286, in create_tables
    model.create_table(**options)

  File "/app/lib/python3.7/site-packages/peewee.py", line 6595, in create_table
    cls._schema.create_all(safe, **options)

  File "/app/lib/python3.7/site-packages/peewee.py", line 5731, in create_all
    self.create_table(safe, **table_options)

  File "/app/lib/python3.7/site-packages/peewee.py", line 5586, in create_table
    self.database.execute(self._create_table(safe=safe, **options))

  File "/app/lib/python3.7/site-packages/peewee.py", line 3112, in execute
    return self.execute_sql(sql, params, commit=commit)

  File "/app/lib/python3.7/site-packages/peewee.py", line 3106, in execute_sql
    self.commit()

  File "/app/lib/python3.7/site-packages/peewee.py", line 2873, in __exit__
    reraise(new_type, new_type(exc_value, *exc_args), traceback)

  File "/app/lib/python3.7/site-packages/peewee.py", line 183, in reraise
    raise value.with_traceback(tb)

  File "/app/lib/python3.7/site-packages/peewee.py", line 3099, in execute_sql
    cursor.execute(sql, params or ())

peewee.DatabaseError: database disk image is malformed
```

Thank you!

Comment: this question might be better suited for https://askubuntu.com/

Answer (score 0):

I did a simple search via the terminal!
Command:

```
find . -type f -name "*.db"
```

Result:

> ./.var/app/com.leinardi.gwe/config/gwe/gwe.db

I just deleted it! Problem solved!